# JQuery: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have no idea whatsoever why I am getting this error (I read every topic with a similar name but the answers to those questions didn't apply):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

postAndFade($node, post_key) {
    var id = $node.parents.('.id').find('.id-value').text();
    var post_val = $node.text();
    $node.fadeOut('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "id="+id+"&"+post_key+"="+post_val,
        success: function(data) {
            $node.html(data);
            $node.fadeIn('slow');           
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('.featured-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($this, 'featured'); });
$('.visible-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($this, 'visible'); });

});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery?  Are you loading the jquery.js locally or an external CDN?

Comment: CDN, latest version I believe

Comment: Next time I would recommend running your code through jsLint or jsBin (or whatever).  Or maybe utilize YUI or Google's Closure syntax checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
postAndFade($node, post_key) {
```

You're missing the `function` keyword.

```
var id = $node.parents.('.id').find('.id-value').text();
```

You have an extra `.` after `parents`.

Comment: thanks everyone, I will accept this answer since Jeremy picked up on two things.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't declaring a function here with the keyword `function`.

```
postAndFade($node, post_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be this:

```
function postAndFade($node, post_key) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the keyword `function` before you define your function `postAndFade`.